# Transform Orientations locked on "View"

Tags: interface, transforms, transform-orientation

I have a scene that was passed off to me,
for whatever reason I can't get it to go out of "View" for Transform Orientations.
I've tried setting it to Global, Local etc, but it persists. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upper right of Blender's 3D viewport, under the Gizmos dropdown,
"Object Gizmos" needs to be switched from "View", to something else, typically "Default".
"View" will make it orient to the user's view, regardless of what it's set to under the Transform Orientations dropdown.

[image: object gizmo location]